# Howto list EPSG codes as proj.4 strings from the new Proj 6 sqlite3 proj.db

Tags: proj, sqlite

I want to list all EPSG codes from the new PROJ.6 tool in form of `proj.4` strings. Is there a tool / SQL script to replicate the former `/usr/share/proj/epsg` file from the SQLite3 `proj.db`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Python for this purpose

Install the Python lib

```
# use version 2.4.2 as it install a version 6 of proj behind the scene
python3 -m pip install pyproj==2.4.2 pyproj
```

Then, run the following Python script

```py
import os
import pyproj

all_epsg_crs_code = pyproj.get_codes('EPSG', 'CRS')

# Be aware that with to_proj4 usage you will get below warning
# UserWarning: You will likely lose important projection information when
# converting to a PROJ string from another format. See:
# https://proj.org/faq.html#what-is-the-best-format-for-describing-coordinate-reference-systems


with open('/tmp/epsg', 'w') as input_file:
    for i in all_epsg_crs_code:
        my_proj = pyproj.CRS("epsg:{}".format(i))
        old_epsg_string_format = """# {}{}<{}> {} <>""".format(
            my_proj.name,
            os.linesep,
            i,
            my_proj.to_proj4()
        )
        input_file.write(old_epsg_string_format)
```

You may want to set the path to your proj version content using https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/dev/installation.html#envvar-PROJ_DIR as by default Pyproj install it own binary/lib of proj.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your code snippet. Have you an idea, why the description of SRS goes forward to much more complicated WKT notation. In terms of comandline usage like in the proj.4  notation to the WTK one is not handy anymore.

Comment: Already mentioned in the code snippet but here the clickable link https://proj.org/faq.html#what-is-the-best-format-for-describing-coordinate-reference-systems. As I do not need projections with specific parameters, proj.4 or WKT are the same for me. Can't understand your pain in this case, just sympathize

Comment: Direct transformations between datums aren't possible with Proj.4 since the definitions can be ambiguous. That's one of the main reasons for the deprecation of proj.4

Comment: Yes I've scrolled through the code version 6 and 7 and since version 5, a lot of code refactoring is done, including new UTM transformation features. Code improvements are fine, but I'm a fan of breaking of long-term running legacy code by adding  features or changing  the behaviour of the complete tool set. If you check the code, it is planed that version 8 the proj.4 strings will be deprecated.  Pitty is that, new code breaks the UNIX philosophy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy. The larger form of SRS definitions breaks "Interactive use instead of batch processing." for example.